# Error al probar la aplicacion ionic en el celular

Tags: java, ionic, cordova

Quiero probar la aplicación  en ionic en el celular, no en un emulador, al ejecuar el comando:

```
ionic run android
```

y tener el celular en modo depuración activado y conectado al PC, recibo el siguiente error:

```
 Error ocurred  during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for 2097152KB object heap

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What want wrong:
unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvmoption is used.
Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/2.14.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
Please read the following process output to find out more:
```

Comment: Podrías agregar en tu pregunta el error, pero como texto. Gracias

Comment: @Fabian ¿En que entorno trabajas? ¿Linux, Windows, MAC?

Comment: @Naos WIndows 10,  32 bits, el jdk de java es la version para 32 bits

Comment: @Fabian prueba intentando lo que describo en mi respuesta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto me pasó a mi hace un tiempo y lo solucioné de está manera:

1. Abre una *consola* como **administrador** (como mencionas que estás en windows 10 lo haces presionando la tecla *windows + x* y *clickando* *"Símbolo del sistema(administrador)"*).
2. Escribes en ella (la *consola*) el siguiente *comando*:

   > set _JAVA_OPTIONS=-Xmx512M
3. **Reinicia** la computadora y prueba de nuevo

Esta es otra manera de realizar lo anterior (a mi parecer un poco más larga):

Accede a: *Panel de Control (debes tener la vista en **Categorías**) -> Sistema y Seguridad -> Sistema -> Configuración Avanzada del sistema (Está en modo de "TAB" al lado izquierdo) -> Variables de entorno*

Allí le das click en "*Nueva*" en donde pondrás `_JAVA_OPTIONS` como "**Nombre de la**" y `-Xmx512M` como "**Valor de la**", das aceptar, reinicias la computadora y pruebas de nuevo.

Comment: Muchas gracias, eso resolvió mi problema

Answer (score 1):

Prueba escribiendo en el terminal

```
ionic run android --device
```

Edit:

Prueba lo siguiente:

```
Ejecuta en la terminal "adb kill-server"
Espera 20 segundos y conecta el móvil al PC.
Ejecuta en la terminal "adb start-server"
Comprueba los dispositivos conectados con "adb
devices" en la terminal.
```

Comment: También intente escribiendo eso y me sale el mismo error

Comment: He actualizado el post pruébalo y nos cuentas

Comment: Lo probare en cuanto llegue a mi casa, gracias.